# Google.Apis code won't executre after publishing Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oauth, google-calendar-api, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook add-in that will sync your Outlook calendar to your Google calendar. The add-in works great during testing and debugging, but once it is published (Using One Click Manifest) it throws an error (Picture Below).  The add-in is not being disabled from the error.

Here is the code used to 'log-in' to Google.

```
    public void Create_Service()
    {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "*******",
                    ClientSecret = "***********",
                },
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;

            service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "******",
            });
    }
```

Here is the error.

What would cause this to work during debug and testing, but not after publish (on the same computer mind you)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tronal,

Did you have a chance to check the COM Add-ins list in Outlook? Is your add-in listed as active there?

> Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.
>
> Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.
>
> Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.
>
> When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article in MSDN.

Comment: I should have clarified. The add-in is not being disabled.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code or create a log file?

Comment: Finally got it to throw an error after publish by changing my error handling methods. I posted a pic of it. What do you think? Again. this error doesn't get thrown during debugging.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the required assemblies to the ClickOnce installer.

Comment: How to I deploy it with the installer. Shouldn't it deploy automatically when published if it's required? You're right, I don't see it in the Application Files Folder, so it's not being sent with the build.

Comment: See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

After days of research I finally figured out the issue, as well as realized my terrible spelling in the title of my post.

The issue is with the ClickOnce installer not publishing all of the required dll's. I guess this is a known issue that Microsoft has yet to fix. What I did to fix this was go through all of the reference files in my project and compare them to the reference files in my published folder.

I then imported all of the missing files into my project directly as new items (this caused a caution, because I had .dll files in my project that matched reference files, but who cares if it fixes the issue). Then once I published again, the publisher exported the missing files and everything began to work. HOORAY!